# OpenCV library error when compiling with CMake and Make: cannot find -lopencv_bgsegm

Tags: c++, opencv, makefile, cmake, cc

I was trying to build a repo located [HERE](https://github.com/Pratik08/Vis-DSS). As per instructions, I created a `CMakeLists`, and updated the directory addresses inside. I was not sure about the OpenCV path, but found two candidates and inserted both.

`Cmake` is good, but when doing `make`, I get this error, which I guess is maybe due to the openCV path being incorrect.

Here is the VERBOSE output:

```
[100%] Linking CXX executable SimpleVideoSummExample
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/SimpleVideoSummExample.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++    -O3 -std=c++0x -std=c++0x -fopenmp  -s CMakeFiles/SimpleVideoSummExample.dir/src/utils/ShotDetector.cc.o CMakeFiles/SimpleVideoSummExample.dir/src/videoSummarization/SimpleVideoSummarizer.cc.o CMakeFiles/SimpleVideoSummExample.dir/src/utils/ColorUtils.cc.o CMakeFiles/SimpleVideoSummExample.dir/src/utils/ImageUtils.cc.o CMakeFiles/SimpleVideoSummExample.dir/examples/SimpleVideoSummExample.cc.o  -o SimpleVideoSummExample  -L/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/3.4.1_2/lib -rdynamic libsummengine.a -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_bgsegm -lopencv_video -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_dnn -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/3.4.1_2/lib
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopencv_bgsegm
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/SimpleVideoSummExample.dir/build.make:199: recipe for target 'SimpleVideoSummExample' failed
make[2]: *** [SimpleVideoSummExample] Error 1
```

What is the problem? How to fix it?

Here is the directory part of `CMakeLists` (Cellar is the git repo's user):

```
include_directories(/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/3.4.1_2/include/ /usr/local/Cellar/opencv/3.4.1_2/include/opencv/ /usr/include/opencv /usr/local/include/opencv$
link_directories(/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/3.4.1_2/lib/)
add_executable(SimpleVideoSummExample src/utils/ShotDetector.cc src/videoSummarization/SimpleVideoSummarizer.cc src/utils/ColorUtils.cc src/utils/ImageUtils$
target_link_libraries(SimpleVideoSummExample
    summengine -lopencv_imgproc
    -lopencv_core
    -lopencv_highgui
    -lopencv_videoio
    -lopencv_imgcodecs
    -lopencv_bgsegm
    -lopencv_video
    -lopencv_objdetect
    -lopencv_dnn
)
```

Comment: Try running `make` with `VERBOSE=1`. Can you post the output of it, so we can see what is being provided to the linker?

Comment: Also, the use of [`link_directories`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/link_directories.html) is discouraged wherever possible. Documentation suggests to use the full path to each library in the `target_link_libraries` command instead.

Comment: @squareskittles updated with the verbose output.

Comment: regarding your 2nd comment, I don't know anything about that. Please help.

Comment: So based on your updated question, the linker is looking here `/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/3.4.1_2/lib` for your opencv libraries. Can you verify that they all exist in that folder (e.g. libopencv_bgsegm.so)?

Comment: So I have to update the `link_directories` (not the `include_directories`)? Actually the only openCV directories I have on my PC are `/usr/include/opencv` and `/usr/local/include/opencv`...and none have that file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198892/discussion-between-squareskittles-and-tina-j).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the Github repository you are using doesn't explicitly state it in the documentation, it appears you not only need OpenCV, but also need to build the *extra* OpenCV [modules](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/tree/master/modules/bgsegm) (hinted by [this](https://answers.opencv.org/question/184963/opencv-version-34-undefined-reference-to-cvbgsegmcreatebackgroundsubtractormogint-int-double-double/) answer). The missing `opencv_bgsegm` library is provided by these "extra" OpenCV modules.

Following a tutorial such as [this](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html), you should include the CMake definition flag:

`-DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/path/to/opencv_contrib/modules/`

when running `cmake`. This will ensure the extra modules are built, and the `opencv_bgsegm` library will be available on your system.